# Pandas Correlation - How to use df.corr() ignoring 0 in both columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan, correlation

How can i use `df.corr()` ignoring all the times that i have 0 in both columns?
I have data **with more than two columns** and want know all correlations ignoring all (0,0).

```
#dataframe without zeros for both columns
df = pd.Dataframe([(.2, .3), (.1, .2), (.3, .6), (.6, .9), 
    (.5, .0), (.0, .5)], columns = ['dogs', 'cats'])
ρ = corr(dogs,cats) = 0.2482

#dataframe with lots of zeros for both columns
df = pd.Dataframe([(.2, .3), (.1, .2), (.3, .6), (.6, .9), 
    (.5, .0), (.0, .5), (.0, .0), (.0, .0), (.0, .0), (.0, .0)],
    columns = ['dogs', 'cats'])
ρ = corr(dogs,cats) = 0.5743

#dataframe with np.NaN instead of every zero
df = pd.Dataframe([(.2, .3), (.1, .2), (.3, .6), (.6, .9), 
    (.5, .0), (.0, .5), (.0, .0), (.0, .0), (.0, .0), (.0, .0)],
    columns = ['dogs', 'cats'])
df = df.replace(0, np.NaN)
ρ = corr(dogs,cats) = 0.9759
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda row: False if np.sum(row) == 0 else True, axis=1)
```

The above code will generate a series with `True` and `False`, where `False` happened when all the columns are zeros.

So, you just need to use the mask to filter your dataframe.

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda row: False if np.sum(row) == 0 else True, axis=1)]
df.corr()
```